# Is semicolon optional at the end of if expression in bash script?

Tags: bash

In bash script, the bracket quoted expression of an `if` statement has no semicolon to the right of `]`, according to the section **Programming with Shell Scripts** of this [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023029.do).

But the semicolon can be seen at many different tutorials or scripts, such as this [tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.1) and this script snippet:

```
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi
```

When do I have to put semicolon there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the `then` on the same line, then you need a semi-colon. If not, it's optional.

```
if x; then
    y
fi

if x
then
    y
fi
```

Think of it as how you write two commands. You can write either

```
foo
bar
```

or

```
foo; bar
```